# How to code in Visual Studio 6.0 without UI editor

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-6

I'm new to Visual Basic. I have done some tutorials in Visual Studio 2010 and I am working with Visual Basic 6.0.

I don't know where I can write code the way I did in VB 2010. Instead of the code editor that was available in Visual Studio 2010, I get a UI editor, where I can add buttons. How can I simply write some Visual Basic code?

Comment: Yup, VB6 is really old school... :)

Comment: If you remove the VS2010 tag you won't get as many useless snide comments from the peanut gallery.

Answer (score 4):

In VB6, there is a code view.  If you double click the button it will take you to the click event in the code view for instance.

If you create modules.. (.bas file extension), you can write stand alone code.  It's also possible to create an activex dll project to write code components.  I used to do this, register them with com and then call them from ASP pages on NT4 servers back in the day.

VB6 predates the .NET framework though.  It's much different than what you've learned in Visual Studio 2010.  None of the .NET libraries are there and there are some syntax differences as VB.net is more strict than VB6 is.

Answer (score 0):

You code use other editors alongside VB 6's editor like Notepad ++ and Sublime Text if you are really good in VB othersise just stick to it. Its very cool and people are making world class apps with vb6 check planetsourcecode.com you see wonders